How can I restore Yarn after accidentally deleting the .yarn folder?
After unintentionally deleting the .yarn folder in my home directory, I encountered an error when trying to run the yarn command:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v21.7.3

I attempted to completely uninstall Yarn from my machine by removing it using the package manager with pacman -R yarn, and also via npm with npm uninstall -g yarn. Despite reinstalling it afterward, the error persists. Additionally, I tried removing Corepack and Node.js and reinstalling them, but this did not resolve the issue.

Do which yarn to figure out why you still have some remnants of yarn left, then clean that up too, then reinstall...

@AKX I have already done that. The output is /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.3/bin/yarn. Despite uninstalling and reinstalling Node.js version 21.7.3, the error persists.

The problem was resolved by deleting the .yarnrc file!

To clarify, ensure that you delete the one that exists in your home directory (~/.yarnrc) or fix it to have the expected configs, but not only the one in your project root directory.
